# Get percentage of current div content

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, sticky

How does one get the percentage of the scroll position inside the current div the user is on? Have some divs in a single html page with multiple screens of text.

Thus when user is on the beginning of the div, it should be 0% and when he scrolls to the middle of the div, 50%, and at the end 100%. If he goes beyond to the next div, it resets relative to new div to 0% as before. looking for a css/and or javascript solution (not jquery).

would like to use this information in a sticky header.

Comment: you can use jquery slider(https://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current position of the page with:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop
```

Then you need to get the positions and height of your divs and calculate the percentage.

Here is an example on how to get a hook on the scroll event:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollleft

Comment: div height is not fixed. it depends on how much text is in there. so how would one get the % within the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the top and height values of your div(s):

```
var top = $('#yourElement').offset().top;
var height = $('#yourElement').height();
```

Then you need to get the current scrollTop value:

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Then you must use these values to calculate the percent:

```
var difference = scrollTop - top;

if((difference > 0) && (difference < height))
    var percent = difference / height;
```

Something along those lines. If you have multiple DIVs you will need to use a for loop to run through each of them.

EDIT:

If jQuery is not an option you may do this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("yourElement");
var top = el.offsetTop;
var height = el.offsetHeight;
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
```

Then you would calculate it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work,Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 
Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
</div>
<div id="box2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 
Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">     
</script>
</html>
```

Here is JS code:

```
let box1 = $('#box1');
let box2 = $('#box2');

$('#box1').scroll(function(){
let val =  (box1.scrollTop()/box1.height())*100;
console.log(val+'%');
})

$('#box2').scroll(function(){
let val =  (box2.scrollTop()/box2.height())*100;
console.log(val+'%');
})
```

Here is css:

```
#box1{
position:absolute;
overflow:scroll;
height:400px;
width:200px;
background:red;
}

#box2{
position:absolute;
overflow:scroll;
height:400px;
width:200px;
background:green;
left:500px;
}
```